# How to write LINQ Join command in lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have written the following JOIN statement in LINQ:

```
var result = (from od in orders
join em in employees on od.EmployeeID equals em.EmployeeID
join ct in customers on od.CustomerID equals ct.CustomerID

select new MyJoin
{
    OrderID = od.OrderID,
    //OrderDate = od.OrderDate,
    ShipCountry = od.ShipCountry,
    CompanyName = ct.CompanyName,
    ContactName = ct.ContactName,
    EmployeeName = (em.FirstName + ' '+em.LastName),
})
```

How would I write this as a lambda expression?

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: What have you triеd?

Comment: The question was to write the JOIN method in LINQ and lambda, I have done it for LINQ, but not sure how to do it with lambda  expressions.

Comment: You are asking someone to write the code for you without showing any evidence of an attempt by yourself. These types of questions are generally frowned on on SO, especially when there are many solutions available online through a quick search.

Comment: There are many examples of this in [so], I just searched for [linq join lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=linq+join+lambda) and got quite a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I offer ReSharper-as-a-Service:

```
var result = orders.Join(employees, 
                         od => od.EmployeeID,
                         em => em.EmployeeID,
                         (od, em) => new { od, em })
                   .Join(customers,
                         od => od.CustomerID,
                         ct => ct.CustomerID,
                         (obj, ct) => new MyJoin
                                      {
                                          OrderID = obj.od.OrderID,
                                          OrderDate = obj.od.OrderDate,
                                          ShipCountry = obj.od.ShipCountry,
                                          CompanyName = ct.CompanyName,
                                          ContactName = ct.ContactName,
                                          EmployeeName = (obj.em.FirstName + ' ' + obj.em.LastName),
                                      });
```

You are using the `Join` extension method:

```
IEnumerable<TResult> Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
            this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer,
            IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
            Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector,
            Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector,
            Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector);
```

For the first call, this is how it relates to your LINQ syntax above:

```
outer: orders
inner: employees
outerKeySelector: od.EmployeeID
innerKeySelector: em.EmployeeID
resultSelector: <this is implied in your LINQ statements>
```

The `outerKeySelector` and `innerKeySelector` are compared with something to the effect of `equals` from your LINQ.

Comment: It doesn't even compile.  In the second `Join`, you need to access the fields of the new anonymous object, e.g. `obj => obj.od.CustomerID` and `(obj, ct) => new MyJoin { OrderID = obj.od.OrderID, /* ... */ CompanyName = ct.CompanyName, /* ... */ EmployeeName = (obj.em.FirstName + ' ' + obj.em.LastName), })`.